# C# WMPLib Duration of a mp3

Tags: c#, audio, mp3, duration, wmplib

Im using WMPLib to make an easy mp3player in C#. Im almost done but theres one more thing I want to do.

I Would like to how far gone the song is and also, how much is left of the song.
using for example the progressbar.

thanks

Adam

Comment: do you mind saying what the program does ? =)

Comment: right now its plays files supported by the WMPLIb :P but i cant figure out how to make get the progressbar to move one second at a time :P

Answer (score 1):

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double percent = 0;
    if (mp.Length != 0)
    percent = ((double) wplayer.controls.currentPosition / wplayer.controls.currentItem.duration);
    progressBar1.Value = (int)(percent * progressBar1.Maximum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an Idea , just try to add statusStrip to your Project Form , and try to add a ToolStripStatusLabel and ToolStripProgressBar to it, and then you can use this simple code , it Works 100% :

```
public void Sound_Progress(ToolStripStatusLabel l1, ToolStripProgressBar psb)
    {   
        //NASSIM LOUCHANI


          int i = Convert.ToInt32(Player.controls.currentItem.duration);
           int j = Convert.ToInt32(Player.controls.currentPosition);
           int Defrence = (i-j);
           l1.Text = Player.controls.currentPositionString + " | " + Player.controls.currentItem.durationString;

            psb.Maximum = i;
            psb.Minimum = 0;

            if (Defrence == i)
                psb.Value = i;
            else if (Defrence != i)
                psb.Value = Defrence;
            else if (Defrence == 0)
                l1.Text = "";

    }
```

And don't forget to add a Timer to your Project Form and put the Sound_Progress(your ToolStripStatusLabel, your ToolStripProgressBar) into your Timer_Tick() Event .

Thank you !